# Infinite Loop when Entering 2 very basic C-strings

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, c-strings

The following code produces an infinite loop when I enter 2 cstrings of entirely 1s and 0s.

What have I done?

```
    char input1[9] = {'\0'};
    char input2[9] = {'\0'};
    bool reEnter = false;


    do
    {
        reEnter = false;
        cout << "The numbers to be added are: "<< endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(input1, 9, '\0');
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(input2, 9, '\0');
        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
        {
            if((input1[i] != '0') && (input1[i] != '1') || (input2[i] != '0') && (input2[i] != '1'))
                {
                reEnter = true;
                }
        }
        if(reEnter == true)
            cout << "Must be an 8 bit binary" << endl;
    }while(reEnter == true);
```

Comment: Seems like 'reEnter' is always true, check the dowhile

Comment: This is not C..

Comment: You should use `'1'` and `'0'`, as your'e dealing with chars.

Comment: The user is inputting binary code so reEnter is supposed to check to be sure that only 0s and 1s are entered. I believe reEnter would be false if all digits are entered correctly. Where am I wrong?

Comment: even if I use '1' and '0', it still produces an infinite loop

Comment: no, this is C++

Comment: But the digits come in ASCII values, meaning '1' will produce a value of 49, for example. If you don't believe me print one of the array cells casted to `int`.

Comment: Why did you tag the question as `c` then?

Comment: I have retagged it as c++, sorry. I also edited it to show '1' and '0', but this still produces the loop

Comment: How do you develop your code? Do you just edit it in Notepad? Get yourself an IDE, such as Eclipse CDT, NetBeans, MS Visual Studio, etc. Learn how to set breakpoints, step through the code, line by line, examine variables and you will soon discover why your loop does not terminate. You have just been taught [how to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) :-)

Comment: Ok, I am supposed to use vim and gdb for class though.

Comment: Btw, when you get your code working, you might find it interesting to post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ You could learn a lot by the comments and explanations there. If you do, please leave a link here to your question

Answer (score 1):

This got it. For some reason it didn't like the ignores, and terminating the cin.getline functions with null characters was creating the infinite loop.

```
char input1[9] = {'\0'};
char input2[9] = {'\0'};
bool reEnter = false;


do
{
    reEnter = false;
    cout << "The numbers to be added are: "<< endl;
    cin.getline(input1, 9);
    cin.getline(input2, 9);
    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if((input1[i] != '0') && (input1[i] != '1') || (input2[i] != '0') && (input2[i] != '1'))
            {
            reEnter = true;
            }
    }
    if(reEnter == true)
        cout << "Must be an 8 bit binary" << endl;
}while(reEnter == true);
```

Comment: Yea ok I get it, the inputs from terminal are not terminated with '\0'. One question though why do you take input of 9 chars? `cin.getline(input2, 9);`

Comment: to leave one character at the end to default to a null terminator. I seem to remember this being an issue otherwise